# Can we rearrange two uncomparable operators to be comparable?

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal{B}\left( H\right) $ be the Banach algebra of all
bounded linear operators defined on a complex Hilbert space
$\left( H;\left\langle \cdot ,\cdot \right\rangle \right)$  with
the identity operator  $1_H$ in $\mathcal{B}\left( H\right) $. Let $A,B\in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ such that
neither $A\le B$ nor $A\ge B$.  Does there exist  an
operator $P\in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ (commutative with $A$)
such that $PA \ge B$?

It seems the answer is positive (yes there is such operator)  but how to prove this generally? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Hint: Let $A=\dots$. Then $PA=A$, regardless of what $P$ you use.

Comment: Let $A = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   2 & 0  \\
   0 & 9  \\
\end{array}} \right)$ and $B = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   3 & 0  \\
   0 & 7  \\
\end{array}} \right)$. Clearly $A-B\le 0$ and $B-A\le 0$ so neither $A\le B$ nor $B\ge A$. For $P
 = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   3 & 0  \\
   0 & 1  \\
\end{array}} \right)$, we have $
PA = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   6 & 0  \\
   0 & 9  \\
\end{array}} \right) \ge B$.

Comment: So what? Giving an example where it's true doesn't show it's always true. Let $A=0$, and choose $B$ so neither $B$ nor $-B$ is positive.

Comment: Yes, I mean we can restrict the assumption to be as required. But how?

Comment: @mwomath Sure: assume that there exists an operator $P$, commuting with $A$, such that $PA\ge B$. Then it is true (and very easy to prove) that there exists an operator $P$,  commuting with $A$, such that $PA\ge B$.

Comment: @mwomath That's not the question you asked. Make up your mind...

Comment: I said does there exist? It is ok forgive my mind. @Whitemale Any suggestion to how we can get such P.

Comment: @mwomath And you asked "...but how to prove this _generally_?". This is getting silly - if someone asks whether $(x+y)^2=x+y$ the answer is _no_, even though $(1+0)^2=1+0$.

Comment: @mwomath Huh? I answered your question. The answer is no. (Hat is, no in general...)

Comment: OK. Thanks for your help.